# Not able inject yaml file into map in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, mapping

I have the following in **application.yml** file

```
org:
  "001"
    "001"
      name: somename
      location: somelocation
  "002"
    "001"
      name: somename
      location: somelocation
```

**MyData.java**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "org")
public class MyData {
Map<String, Map<String, Metadata>> org = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Metadata>>();
Getter and Setters
}
```

**Metadata.java**

```
public class Metadata {
private String name;
private String location;
Getter and Setters
}
```

**MyController.java**

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

@Autowired
private MyData mydata;

@GetMapping(value = "getMetadata", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Map<String, Map<String, Metadata>> getMetadata(){

Map<String, Map<String, Metadata>> org = mydata.getOrg();
return org;
}
```

The data is not mapped. The response is empty {}. How to resolve this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring tries to populate the variable `org` with prefix `org`, which does not exist.

Introducing the variable `org`, the yml might look like this. Also mind the colons.

```
org:
  org:
    "001":
      "001":
        name: somename
        location: somelocation
    "002":
      "001":
        name: somename
        location: somelocation
```